# Laravel Mix / Webpack: Pack Tailwind Stylesheet per folder

Tags: webpack, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

I'm currently working on a Laravel Project, which auto-generates catalogues for shops. Each shop has its own template and views:

e.g. resources/templates/example_template contains the main stylesheet and resources like images

and resources/views/example_template contains corresponding twig views, which are compiled during generation.

Currently these projects live on their own handwritten stylesheets, but as the rest of the front-end is built on Tailwind, I'd like to build these with Tailwind in the future

My main problem currently is the Laravel Mix / webpack generation of the individual templates, as I'd prefer not having a postcss block per template. Ideally even a general tailwind-config but having a tailwind-config per template is probably unavoidable.

Current webpack:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .copyDirectory('resources/templates', 'public/templates')
    .copyDirectory('resources/img', 'public/img')
    .copyDirectory('resources/fonts', 'public/fonts')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
    .alias({
        '@': 'resources/js',
    });


if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a similar issue, I solved it like this:

```
const templates = []


templates.map(template => {
    const template_underscore = template.replace('-', '_') + '_template/'
    return mix.postCss(
        'resources/views/catalogue/'+template_underscore+'/catalogue.css',
        'public/templates/'+template+'/catalogue.css',
        [require('postcss-import'), require('tailwindcss')('./resources/views/catalogue/'+template_underscore+'tailwind-catalogue.config.js')]
    )
})
```